# typescript says p.a can be undefined in body of if (p.a !== undefined)

Tags: typescript, undefined

```
type T = {
    a?: {[key:string]:boolean}
}
const f = (p: T):void => {
    if (p.a !== undefined) {
        Object.keys(p.a).forEach(k => { p.a[k] = false;})
    }
}
```

p.a in `p.a[k]` is erroneously underlined with message: "Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)".

Changing `if (p.a !== undefined) {` by `if (!p.a) {` doesn't help.

Comment: you made the property `a` optional which means it has type `[key:string]:boolean | undefined`

Comment: @MikeS.yes thanks I know that... why do you think I have written if (p.a !== undefined)

Comment: I guess it should be clear by now, considering there are a few answers, I just wanted to add: `p.a !== undefined` is not the same as `!p.a`. if `a` is defined, `p.a !== undefined` will be true, `!p.a` will be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to sebbab for the link to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30576

That github issue has been closed because there the handler can be called AFTER the parent objet has been changed.
That's not the case here, but to know it Typescript would need to make  kind of run-time analysis of the code executed in the forEach function which is difficult/impossible.

Based on that, the solution I prefer is:

```
type T = {
    a?: {[key:string]:boolean}
}
const f = (p: T): void => {
    const t = p.a;
    if (t !== undefined) {
        Object.keys(t).forEach(k => { t[k] = false;})
    }
}
```

EDIT: actually the best solution for my personal taste is:
-no forEach
-no hasOwnProperty

```
type T = {
    a?: {[key:string]:boolean}
}
const f = (p: T):void => {
    if (p.a !== undefined) {
        for (const k of Object.keys(p.a)) {
            p.a[k] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem relies on scopes.

`p.a[k] = false;` runs inside the function that you declared for the forEach loop. That function is not in the same scope that checks the existence of `p.a`, hence, typescript can not guarantee that `p.a` will not be undefined.

More info can be found in this related issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30576

You can fix this in several ways. One obvious but weird way could be:

```
if (p.a !== undefined) {
  Object.keys(p.a).forEach(k => {
    if (p.a !== undefined) {
      p.a[k] = false
    }
  })
}
```

The other one, if `p.a` is just an object literal as your typing says, could be:

```
for (let k in p.a) {
  p.a[k] = false
}
```

You don't even need to check `if (p.a !== undefined) {` here.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the new scope of the `forEach` handler, you could just use a `for...in` loop:

```
type T = {
    a?: {[key:string]:boolean}
}
const f = (p: T) => {
    if (p.a !== undefined) {
        for (const k in p.a) {
            if(p.a.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
               p.a[k] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestion of using the for in loop, however, why do you think the reason for this issue is related to the typings of Object.keys?

Comment: I meant the combination of `Object.keys` and `forEach`, in this case I think it's more about the `forEach` that doesn't take you type guard (p.a !== undefined) into account, because the handler is a new scope

Comment: avoiding forEach avoids to create new scope and solves the issue. I don't like "hasOwnProperty though, and I solve that by using for...of on Object.keys